# iptables mangle table with custom chain

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

I create a new chain in mangle table:

```
$IPTABLES -N newchain -t mangle
```

After that all the 80's port packets I put to that new chain:

```
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j newchain
```

After that I mark up the packets of this chain:

```
$IPTABLES -t mangle -A newchain -j MARK --set-mark 11
```

How can I dnat those packets, that are marked with 11 after that?

```
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 11 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.32.1.2
```

Doesnt work. Cause after newchain in mangle > packets are going to filter FORWARD, but not to the nat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAT is applied after the routing has been determined. So ou need to use the POSTROUTING table -

```
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 11 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.32.1.2
```

I'm not sure why you'd need to continue the qualification of tcp/80 too though, as you have marked them on that basis already.

```
$IPTABLES -t nat -A POSTROUTING -m mark --mark 11 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.32.1.2
```

Comment: I've figured out the following:
works fine if I DNAT to the router itself. if DNAT to other machine — not. why?